# How to find out which submit button was pressed in node js?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, model-view-controller

I have form which looks like this , now how will the controller/admin know which submit button was pressed  ?

```
   <form method="POST">
         <input type="submit" value="Add Admin" name="addAdmin">
         <input type="submit" value="All Employee List" name="allEmployeeList">
         <input type="submit" value="Update"  name="update">
         <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete">
         <a href="login">Login</a>
     </form>
```

what are the conditions that I need to write inside the router.post function  to validate which submit button was pressed ?

```
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
     

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are writing your code using a middleware such as express to handle routing and other misc jobs.

The best way to resolve your problem would be to use a `bodyparser` which would help you pick up queries as object properties from the body.

You would also want to change the HTML so you would use a `button` to submit instead of an `input`. The reason being you are sending "commands" to server to perfrom an action. The best way imo to send commands is to send a command object which you could intercept on server side and then pull commands off the object.

In order to do so you need to change the `input` submit buttons to `button` submit button and then pass in the `command name` that you wish to use in `name` field of the element. In this example, I am using the command name as "action", You can choose anything you like.

```
<button type="submit" value="allEmployeeList" name="action">List Employees</button>
```

This would then send the payload as

```
{
    action: allEmployeeList
}
```

You could then use `request.body.action` to pull the "command" out and then run additional code based on the command encountered.

Here's a sample implementation that could help you out: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-surf-lud12?file=/src/index.js